# How to compare between two incomparable things, yet similar in some aspects?

Tags: phrases, expressions, comparisons

I want to compare between results seen in healthy cells and in tumor cells. The same finding was seen in both types of cells. I know that this is not like apples-to-apples comparison, but still both cell types can share some cellular properties that are not yet affected by the tumor development. In this case the comparison is to some degree tenable.
Now I want to express this in a short phrase, the nearest thing came to my mind was:

1. Although the comparison between cells A and B is not straightforward, there was an agreement between the two to show...
2. Despite the fact that cells A and B are not directly comparable, they were in agreement to show...
3. Despite the different nature of cells A and B, both were in agreement to show...
4. (I am more inclined to use this, but I am not sure how, here is my trial):
   As much as the comparison allows between A and B cells, both cells showed...

I am not sure which one fits more in this context, may be there is a more professional way to say it? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Although...

- comparison of cells A and B was not straightforward,
- cells A and B were generally dissimilar,

some...

- similarities
- commonalities
- shared features

...

- emerged.
- were observed.
- were noted.

Both cells...

- showed
- shared

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like "shared aspects" or "common traits" would be proper?